# I've planted too many potatoes in 1 container

Tags: containers, potatoes, thinning

I'm a very novice gardener.  In one potato sack I planted about 10 seed potatoes which I have since learnt is far too many.  Is my potato harvest doomed?   Can I remove some of the plants?

Comment: How recently did you plant them? The longer they've been in the harder the situation is to salvage

Comment: It might not be too bad. You just did wasted 9 potatoes... You could move the plants to a bigger bag. This relates to http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/growing-potatoes-in-small-space

Comment: You'll end up with lots of tiny potatoes. Best to remove most and leave a couple behind if you can.

Comment: Shoot, go for a vertical growing techique!  Set chicken wire in a circle around the perimeter of your pot, fill with straw leaving 5 or 6" greenery above the straw.  Keep filling with straw as the plant grows upward.  This works really well!! Try not to use your own seed potatoes.  You get just one with a disease and you lose all.  Also do not plant potatoes or tomatoes or peppers in the same soil every year.  Called rotation.  Harvest potatoes to encourage more growth and actually eat your own crop.

Answer (score 4):

I did that with beets and carrots a few years back.  What happens is the vegetables start competing for space underground and end up either being smaller in size or malformed.  I would suggest gently taking out 7-8 of these and transplanting them.  Of course, it would all depend on where they are in their maturity cycle